# JavaFX how to dynamical enable Menuitem line & context Popup over Path object

Tags: javafx, path, menuitem

I have 2 more questions

1) Do you know how to dynamically dis/enable an option in a HBox or VBox drop down ? For example in a game which is in either state "A" or "B". When in state "A" I would like to enable a certain option (depicted as a MenuItem option A). When in state "B" I would like to enable a certain option (depicted as a MenuItem option B). The H/VBox has 1 line/state. Either active or inactive.

2) How can you have a contextMenu pop up when clicking on a Path object. For example I would like have a contextMenu which allows repainting the underlying Path object in a certain color.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't ask multiple questions in the same post.

1) Call `menuItem.setDisable(...)` when the state changes. If the state is represented by an [observable property](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107), then you can do this in a listener or a binding; otherwise you just have to organize your code so that you know whenever the state is changed.

2) Register a mouse listener on the path object, and call

```
contextMenu.show(path, mouseEvent.getScreenX(), mouseEvent.getScreenY());
```

in the listener.